# Can't run npm start in reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, npm-start

I cloned a Github repository. Once cloned I ran the **npm install** command. When I try to run **npm start** I get the following error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAF5Q.png)

What am I supposed to do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is trying to load "initrd.img" and not able to find that image file. Can you do a local search on your machine to verify whether this file is present?

You can also verify error messages in "*debug.log" which is mentioned in your error message.